# dose SONY Camera SDK support setter API such as setIsoSpeedRate , setShutterSpeed on A7

Tags: sdk, camera, sony

I want to  develop a camera tool on Android , need to set shutter speed ,aperture ,IOS remotly base on  Manual mode.
My camerra is Sony A7.

when I call getMethodTypes , i can see
       setFNumber
       setIsoSpeedRate
       setShutterSpeed
in result list

but i can not  see it avalible  in my getAvailableApiList.

dose someone have this experience on this issue?

Comment: And I Use Canon lens with a converter , does that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'pySony' project on git-hub there is a simple script to dump capabilities:
https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api/blob/master/src/example/dump_camera_capabilities.py

Maybe reviewing/looking at that will help you out, note the line(s) about enabling 'startRecMode()'.

For my HX60 the callable functions are...

- setShutterSpeed
- getShutterSpeed
- getAvailableShutterSpeed
- getSupportedShutterSpeed

with:

> getSupportedShutterSpeed : {'result':
>      [['30"', '25"', '20"', '15"', '13"', '10"', '8"', '6"', '5"', '4"',
>      '3.2"', '2.5"', '2"', '1.6"', '1.3"', '1"', '0.8"', '0.6"', '0.5"',
>      '0.4"', '1\/3', '1\/4', '1\/5', '1\/6', '1\/8', '1\/10',
>      '1\/13', '1\/15', '1\/20', '1\/25', '1\/30', '1\/40', '1\/50',
>      '1\/60', '1\/80', '1\/100', '1\/125', '1\/160', '1\/200',
>      '1\/250', '1\/320', '1\/400', '1\/500', '1\/640', '1\/800',
>      '1\/1000', '1\/1250', '1\/1600']], 'id': 1}

- setIsoSpeedRate
- getIsoSpeedRate
- getAvailableIsoSpeedRate
- getSupportedIsoSpeedRate

with:

> getSupportedIsoSpeedRate : {'result':
>      [['AUTO', '80', '100', '200', '400', '800', '1600', '3200']], 'id':
>      1}

Note, as you alluded, some functions are only usable in particular modes.